# Ownerdrawn Winform Button: Handling AcceptButton cues

Tags: c#, winforms, button, ownerdrawn

I've made my own custom ownerdrawn button control, inherited from the Button class itself. I draw the control all by myself in the `OnPaint` override procedure, this includes painting the background of the button, drawing its borders, text and image.

I also need to incorporate the capability for the button to show an Active color border in case the button has focus, or is defined as the `AcceptButton` by the parent form. For focus, I use `this.ContainsFocus` to know if the button currently has focus.

How to know if my button control is defined as the default `AcceptButton` on the parent form, so I can draw the active border color around it accordingly? I don't see any inherited property in the `Button` class to find this out.

Thanks.

Comment: The Parent Form knows and it calls the `NotifyDefault()` method when the AcceptButton is set.

Comment: Your Button has a IsDefault Property that should reflect this.

Comment: @Ralf That's what the (overridable) `NotifyDefault()` method sets :) (which in turn sets the [BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) style)

Comment: What I means is that, when custom-drawing a Button Control, you need to override `NotifyDefault()`, so the default style is not applied and you can replace it with your own designed *style*. A description here: [Flat Button Style - Hide border and Focus Cue when the Button is active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64190445/7444103)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi and Ralf. This solves my problem! :-)